# Can not apply rxjs .map() method on Response

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

In MyComponent.ts I can this code:

```
this.testService.saveChanges(testTypesToSave, this.schoolyearId, 

this.currentSubject.id, this.currentSchoolclass.id).subscribe(testTypes => {

     let testTypeViewModels = testTypes.map(t => new AssignedTestType(t));
      this.testTypes.push(...testTypeViewModels);  
    });
```

The .map() method does not exist on the testTypes getting error:

```
Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Response'.
```

That is correct!

The payload is behind the respose.json() method, but I do not want to call that method TWICE in the http service AND in the component.

Thats how the server call is done:

```
  saveChanges(testTypes: AssignedTestType[], schoolyearId: number, subjectId: number, schoolclassId: number): Observable<Response> {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        let dto = {
            testTypes: testTypes.map(t =>
                ({ name: t.name, weight: t.weight, testTypeId: t.id })),
            schoolyearId: schoolyearId,
            subjectId: subjectId,
            schoolclassId: schoolclassId// put this prop on serverside too
        };
        return this.http.post('/api/testtypes', dto, options).map(response => response.json());
```

So how can I get my data in the component without calling .json() a 2nd time and I should be able to apply the .map() method on the response payload ?!

**UPDATE**

during coding time the response. shows response.json(), but during runtime the response is my testTypes Array.

That means I must be possible to apply the .map() on the response when I give it a type... but WHAT type? Its typeless from the server.

I am using:

```
   "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/common": "^2.0.0",
```

Comment: You are already returning `.map(response => response.json())` so the subscriber receives decoded JSON so I guess the problem is someplace else.

Comment: yes but where... I already use the .map() function in that component, so all needed is imported! Updated the tools versions I use.

Comment: Ok stupid approach, but I removed the Observable<Response> then the .map() method works!

Comment: @Elisabeth That's because you're mapping response object. It returns `Observable<any>`.